# NumberFormat.parse() does not work for FRANCE Locale space as thousand seperator

Tags: locale, number-formatting

I have written below Java code to see how locales behave with numbers. I am facing with FRENCH style.

```
double n = 123456789.123;
System.out.println("US              "+ NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(n));    //###,###.###
System.out.println("FRENCH          "+ NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRENCH).format(n)); // # ###,##
System.out.println("GERMAN          "+ NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(n)); // ###.###,##

System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse("123,451.23"));
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("123.451,23"));
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("123 451,23"));
```

OUTPUT

```
US              123,456,789.123
FRENCH          123 456 789,123
GERMAN          123.456.789,123
123451.23
123451.23
123
```

As you can see space is used as thousands separator for FRENCH locale. But when I tried to generate number "123 451,23" it does not recognize space as thousands separator.

Is this the expected behavior ?

**EDIT:**
As a workaround I replaced space with ".". So number becomes a GERMANY format. And then convert it using that locale.

```
input = input.replace(" ", ".");
// Now "123 451,23" is "123.451,23" So which is same as german
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(input));
```

OUTPUT

```
123451.23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in old JDKs.  Upgrade it or you will this [issue](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4510618)