# Numberformat.parse not working correctly for french locale in java

Tags: java, number-formatting

In my code, I am getting the locale value and using it in the below snippet of code :

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
    double value = nf.parse(input).doubleValue();
```

For en_gb locale and fr_fr locale the input provided is the same i.e, 1,000.00.
But the "value" is 1000.0 for en_gb locale and 1.0 for fr_fr locale.

Did try to search for solutions in the below posts :
1][NumberFormat.parse() does not work for FRANCE Locale space as thousand seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478546/numberformat-parse-does-not-work-for-france-locale-space-as-thousand-seperator)
2] http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6318800

but no luck. Any thoughts/pointers on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You're parsing a string, which is '1,000.00'. The problem is, in France locale, the correct format of number 1000 is '1 000'. That's why you ended up getting an output of '1'.

An simple example is:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

double d = 1000.00;
System.out.println(nf.format(d));

NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);

System.out.println(nf1.format(d));
```

The output for France is '1 000' whereas for UK it's '1,000', which means in France, they use space(note its not the same space we can specify by ' ') instead of comma to separate thousand.

In your case, since the input is a string representation of a number, which is '1,000.00', this means it's locale specific and you need to use a right locale format to parse it. This implies that your application should be aware of it's locale from the context. Usually the `NumberFormat` class will just use the default locale, depending on where you run this application and for most cases, that's sufficient.

You do need to provide more detail on what you trying to do and why you're receiving a string as an input.

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.UK);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("1,000"));
```

Comment: Hi Keqiang, Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. Any thoughts/pointers on how to resolve this would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Keqiang. Details as below: The input will always be a string input[i.e, 1,000.00]. We have a website and in every page[say en_gb], this input is used to display in the format [i.e, EUR 1000.00m]. But on the french page due to this issue, it is coming up as [i.e, EUR 1,00m]. We need this data to appear in the same way as it appears in other pages[say en_gb].

Comment: Hi Keqiang, Just to add. The input will always be a string input and the display should be the same for other pages [say en_gb] as well as for fr_fr pages.

Comment: @askdctm So, why is this input string using a comma to separate thousands? If that's always the case, you can specify the `NumberFormat`'s locale always to be 'UK' explicitly so it can parse correctly.

Comment: @askdctm BTW, in France, comma is used to indicate the decimal place, so '1,000' means '1'.

Comment: Hi Keqiang, As mentioned by you I tried to use the same en_gb across all pages. But still its working as before. Not sure where I am missing something.

Comment: public String getLocal(String input){
     Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        String defaultValue = "";
        if(nf!=null){
            try {
                 double value = nf.parse(input).doubleValue();
                 DecimalFormat moneyFormat = (DecimalFormat)nf;
                 moneyFormat.applyPattern("0.00m");
                 defaultValue = moneyFormat.format(value);
            } catch  {
               
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

Comment: Hi Keqiang, Will try on this and post back my results.

Comment: Hi Keqiang, Thanks a lot for your response. Due to some sudden changes, we are not dealing with this scenario now. However, thanks a lot for all your help and assistance.